# Sorting user input into a Stack

Tags: java, string, stack

I have just started with Java, I'm currently using Netbeans. I am trying to sort a user-provided list using stacks. I would like to put different strings into different stacks, based on what the string begins with: k or n. The list provided would be random length strings starting with a k or an n, separated by a new line.

This is my current code:

```
public void sortAction() {

    //Generate a list from user input
    String s[] = listArea.getText().split("//r?//n?//s");
    ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(s));

    //Convert the list into a stack
    Stack<String> mainStack = new Stack<>();
    mainStack.addAll(arrList);

    //Sort mainStack into kStack and nStack
    Stack<String> kStack = new Stack<>();
    Stack<String> nStack = new Stack<>();       
    String temp;

    while (!mainStack.isEmpty()) {
        temp = mainStack.pop();
        if  (temp.startsWith("k")) {
            kStack.push(temp);
        } else {
            nStack.push(temp);
        }

    //Check
    System.out.println(kStack);

    }
```

If I run the code, the console will print everything that the user inputted, as inputted. I think the text isn't split for some reason (listArea is a swing jTextArea). Or maybe I am making a mistake when sorting. Should temp be flushed somehow?

Comment: Have you tested the charAt(0) method on your string evaluation? Instead of starts with?

Comment: How is the is this valid user input?
`kiss`

`nomad`

`normal`

Comment: You need _backslashes_ in your `split()` regex, not regular slashes: `.split("\\r?\\n?\\s")`

Comment: @iamnotmaynard That solved it, thank you so much!